# Udev : detach script to wait for mounting

Tags: sleep, udev

I made a simple udev rule which launch effectively my script :

```
KERNEL=="sdc", ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{manufacturer}=="Bookeen", ATTRS{product}=="Cybook", RUN+="/home/nap/Scripts/Wallabag.sh"
```

The udev rule is properly working, and launch the following script :

```
#!/bin/bash

sleep 5
(
exec </dev/null >/home/nap/usb.log 2>&1
set -x

mkdir /media/nap/Cybook/Test
) &
```

It's supposed to detach and let time to drive to auto-mount, but the mount is still made after the exit of the script.

I've already tried with " & disown" with same effect.

I've also tried to run my script inside another one, as decribed [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/646011/write-files-in-usb-when-connect-by-etc-udev-rules-d), with same effect.

Am I doing something wrong ?

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The processes started by `udev`'s `RUN=` directive should be *short-running*. I would like to suggest a simpler way of *decoupling* long-running process from `udev` by using system scheduler `at` command:

```
KERNEL=="sdc", ACTION=="add", ATTRS{product}=="Cybook", RUN+="/usr/bin/at -M -f /home/nap/Scripts/Wallabag.sh now"
```

Just make sure that your `/home/nap/Scripts/Wallabag.sh` script is `/bin/sh` compatible - this is the shell that `at` uses. It should be more than enough to implement either simple `sleep` delay or polling for `/media/nap/Cybook` availability/readiness.

Comment: Perfect !! Thank you for your anwser :)

Comment: The proper way to say *thank you* at StackExchange sites is by upvoting and accepting helpful answers.